CTKOptionMenu issue with the method .place
CTKOptionMenu issue
I am encountering an issue with the .place() method used on a CTKOptionMenu. As you can see on the screenshot, when I hover on the OptionMenu, the color overfill into the arrow button for any reason.
I also tried the .pack() method and it seems to get rid of the issue but I don't want to use .pack() as I want my widgets to resize with the window using the relheight/relwidth.
I have also included the code for it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
In the meantime, I will keep trying to locate that bug and update if I find out.
class ModifyUserView:
    """Modify user view"""

    def __init__(self, window, main_frame, controller):
        """
            :param window:
            :param main_frame:
            :param controller:
        """
        self.main_frame = main_frame
        self.controller = controller
        self.window = window
        self.title_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.main_frame, text='Modify User', text_color=config.psl_purple_color,
                                        font=('Arial', 40))
        self.modify_user_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.main_frame, text='Select user to modify:',
                                              text_color='white')
        self.select_user_to_modify_menu = ctk.CTkOptionMenu(self.main_frame, values=sorted(  ## CHECK ALL THE CTKOPTION MENU THEY DONT DISPLAY PROPERLY
            [user.username for user in session.query(User).all()]),
                                                            button_color=config.psl_blue_color,
                                                            button_hover_color=config.psl_purple_color,
                                                            dropdown_fg_color=config.psl_blue_color,
                                                            dropdown_hover_color=config.psl_purple_color,
                                                            dropdown_text_color='white',
                                                            fg_color=config.psl_blue_color, anchor='center', dynamic_resizing=True)
        self.username_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.main_frame, text='Username', text_color='white')
        self.username_input = ctk.CTkEntry(self.main_frame, placeholder_text='Username')
        self.password_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.main_frame, text='Password', text_color='white')
        self.password_input = ctk.CTkEntry(self.main_frame, placeholder_text='Password', show='*')
        self.re_password_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.main_frame, text='Password', text_color='white')
        self.re_password_input = ctk.CTkEntry(self.main_frame, placeholder_text='Re-type your password', show='*')
        self.first_name_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.main_frame, text='First Name', text_color='white')
        self.first_name_input = ctk.CTkEntry(self.main_frame, placeholder_text='First Name')
        self.last_name_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.main_frame, text='Last Name', text_color='white')
        self.last_name_input = ctk.CTkEntry(self.main_frame, placeholder_text='Last Name')
        self.user_group_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.main_frame, text='User Group', text_color='white')
        self.user_group_input = ctk.CTkOptionMenu(self.main_frame, values=[group.value for group in UserGroup],
                                                  #SOURCE OF ISSUE FROM PYTEST
                                                  button_color=config.psl_blue_color,
                                                  button_hover_color=config.psl_purple_color,
                                                  dropdown_fg_color=config.psl_blue_color,
                                                  dropdown_hover_color=config.psl_purple_color,
                                                  dropdown_text_color='white', dynamic_resizing=True,
                                                  fg_color=config.psl_blue_color)
        self.modify_user_button = ctk.CTkButton(self.main_frame, text='Modify User', text_color='white',
                                             fg_color=config.psl_blue_color, hover_color=config.psl_purple_color)

    def display(self):
        """Display the modify user view"""
        hide_widgets_in_frame(self.main_frame)
        self.select_user_to_modify_menu.configure(values=sorted([user.username for user in session.query(User).all()]))
        self.title_label.place(anchor='center', relwidth=.2, relheight=.1, relx=.5, rely=.1)
        self.modify_user_label.place(anchor='center', relwidth=.2, relheight=.05, relx=.5, rely=.2)
        self.select_user_to_modify_menu.place(anchor='center',relwidth=.2, relheight=.05, relx=.5, rely=.25)
        self.username_label.place(anchor='center', relwidth=.5, relheight=.05, relx=.5, rely=.3)
        self.username_input.place(anchor='center', relwidth=.2, relheight=.05, relx=.5, rely=.35)
        self.username_input.delete(0,len(self.username_input.get()))
        self.username_input.insert(0,[user.username for user in session.query(User).all()][0])
        self.password_label.place(anchor='center', relwidth=.2, relheight=.05, relx=.5, rely=.4)
        self.password_input.place(anchor='center', relwidth=.2, relheight=.05, relx=.5, rely=.45)
        self.password_input.delete(0, len(self.password_input.get()))
        self.password_input.insert(0, [user.password for user in session.query(User).all()][0])
        self.re_password_label.place(anchor='center', relwidth=.2, relheight=.05, relx=.5, rely=.5)
        self.re_password_input.place(anchor='center', relwidth=.2, relheight=.05, relx=.5, rely=.55)
        self.re_password_input.delete(0, len(self.re_password_input.get()))
        self.re_password_input.insert(0, [user.password for user in session.query(User).all()][0])
        self.first_name_label.place(anchor='center', relwidth=.2, relheight=.05, relx=.5, rely=.6)
        self.first_name_input.place(anchor='center', relwidth=.2, relheight=.05, relx=.5, rely=.65)
        self.first_name_input.delete(0, len(self.first_name_input.get()))
        self.first_name_input.insert(0, [user.first_name for user in session.query(User).all()][0])
        self.last_name_label.place(anchor='center', relwidth=.2, relheight=.05, relx=.5, rely=.7)
        self.last_name_input.place(anchor='center', relwidth=.2, relheight=.05, relx=.5, rely=.75)
        self.last_name_input.delete(0, len(self.last_name_input.get()))
        self.last_name_input.insert(0, [user.last_name for user in session.query(User).all()][0])
        self.user_group_label.place(anchor='center', relwidth=.2, relheight=.05, relx=.5, rely=.8)
        self.user_group_input.place(anchor='center', relwidth=.2, relheight=.05, relx=.5, rely=.85)
        self.user_group_input.set([user.user_group for user in session.query(User).all()][0].value)
        self.modify_user_button.place(anchor='center', relwidth=.2, relheight=.05, relx=.5, rely=.95)

I did try the .pack() method and seem to get rid of the issue. Also tried to remove most of the arguments passed in the CTKOptionMenu / .place() but without success so far.

Have you tried to use pack in conjunction with it's expand and fill args? You say " I don't want to use .pack() as I want my widgets to resize with the window using the relheight/relwidth." but that's sort of the key feature of pack - it lets widgets resize to their container(s)

You will likely spend far less time using pack and grid than you will using place. While place can be used with relative positioning, it takes a lot of work to get it right.

Hi guys, thanks for the answers. I take it as the easiest solution is to use pack really then?

It's hard to say whether pack or grid is more appropriate. We can't run your code as posted - nothing instantiates ModifyUserView, you don't create a root window, and you haven't defined a config or session objects, and maybe more.

It may be an implementation issue of CTkOptionMenu widget when it is being resized: it does not update the padx setting of the internal label.
To work around it, you can create a custom class based on CTkOptionMenu and update the padx setting whenever the widget is resized by overriding the class method _update_dimensions_event():
class MyCTkOptionMenu(ctk.CTkOptionMenu):
    # override _update_dimensions_event()
    def _update_dimensions_event(self, event):
        # call the original function to update the widget
        super()._update_dimensions_event(event)
        # get the current padx option from grid information
        # note that padx option for the widget is a tuple (left and right padding)
        padx = list(self._text_label.grid_info()['padx'])
        # update the right padding to at least the size of the down arrow
        # which is around the size of the height of the widget
        padx[-1] = padx[0] + event.height
        # update the padx option
        self._text_label.grid(padx=padx)

Note that you can call self._create_grid() instead of updating the padx option after calling super()._update_dimensions_event(event) because the padx option is updated inside self._create_grid() as well.
Then use this custom widget instead of CTkOptionMenu.
